# How to mount the partition?

Tags: mount

My arch was installed on sda3, debian was installed on sda2.
Boot with grub and select menu `arch` to enter into arch.

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="7E91-CA50" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e0c51e12-9954-4cb9-ae62-cebdec976e88"
/dev/sda3: UUID="a872403e-0f73-4c64-8530-0f286fe6a4ee" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="arch" PARTUUID="4329e96c-6d71-4259-9f2a-534b130aae65"
/dev/sda4: UUID="eb4181c2-93ee-4f2d-8e27-5c40512b5293" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="03d13d65-9504-4703-97e8-794171f3a9a7"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="debian" PARTUUID="4bfda6e3-70fa-4316-a01e-475c53e0b51b"
/dev/sda5: PARTUUID="9a1fdb1d-a3c3-494a-a43f-24215320e2cc"

sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F29018A3-5A1D-41A5-B30D-DEF536D2E361

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048 117186559 117184512 55.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  117186560 195311615  78125056 37.3G BIOS boot
/dev/sda3  195311616 312500223 117188608 55.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  312500224 314454015   1953792  954M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  314454016 332031999  17577984  8.4G Linux filesystem
```

I want to mount /dev/sda2  on directory /tmp.

```
sudo mount -t boot   -o  rw  /dev/sda2  /tmp
sudo mount   -o  rw  /dev/sda2  /tmp
```

None of them can mount it.
Why to write the -t argument with boot?
The type info on /dev/sda2 in `sudo fdisk -l`.

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda2  117186560 195311615  78125056 37.3G BIOS boot
```

Comment: What are the error messages that the two mount commands give you?

Comment: Please show us the output from `fdisk -l /dev/sda2` so we can make sure that you didn't get a whole disk image in a partition somehow.  Also, start simple... just `mount /dev/sda2 /tmp` first, then try things like `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /tmp`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems that I can think of.

**1.)** Your debian partition had a valid filesystem but now got corrupted somehow. You can see, that your `/dev/sda2` partition has a boot label (which it should not...), no UUID and no type information about the filesystem. To check that, `fsck /dev/sda2` may give you some sensible output.

**2.)** Your `/dev/sda2` partition is not a partition of `/dev/sda` but rather is a whole device image on its own. To check, whether this is the case, please use `fdisk -l /dev/sda` (which you did in your question) and `fdisk -l /dev/sda2`. The first one should spit out the partition table of your main drive. The latter should have no output at all (except for some device size information).

Maybe you can edit your post to include the outputs. This may lead to a better answer to your question.

**By the way:** The -t argument option in `mount` allows you to explicitly force the disk type to be mounted. Normally you can omit it, as `mount` is able to determine the filesystem type of the partition to be mounted on its own. In your case `mount` may have troubles, because your debian partition *should* be an `ext4` but seems to be *something* else...